# reading from a pipe in c and printing to stdout

Tags: c, pipe

I'm having some trouble reading from a pipe. Well not exactly. I'm reading fine its just the output is globbed up.

```
#include <sys/wait.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int pfd[2];

int main(void)
{
    pid_t   pid;
    int     status;
    char    readbuf[1024];
    int     bytes_read = 0;

    pipe(pfd);

    switch((pid = fork())) {
    case -1:
            perror("fork");
            break;
    case 0:
            /* child */
            close(pfd[0]);
            dup2(pfd[1], 1);        /* stdout */

            /* mkdir -p /home/edgar/testdir */
            chdir("/home/edgar/testdir");

            /* for file in a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z;
             * do
             * touch $file
             * done
             */

            execl("/bin/ls", "ls", "-l", (char *)NULL);
            exit(1);
    default:
            /* parent */
            close(pfd[1]);
            dup2(pfd[0], 0);

            pid = wait(&status);
            /* get input back from ls */
            while ((bytes_read = read(pfd[0], readbuf, sizeof readbuf) > 0)) {
                    fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", readbuf);
            }

            printf("child exit status: %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is an example of globbed up output:

laptop$ ./test1

-rw-r--r--  1 edgar  edgar  0 Jan 31 09:15 u

-rw-r--r--  1 edgar  edgar  0 Jan 31 09:15 v

-rw-r--r--  1 edgar  edgarp��

0 Jan 31 09:15 w
-rw-r--r--  1 edgar  edgar  0 Jan 31 09:15 x

-rw-r--r--  1 edgar  edgar  0 Jan 31 09:15 y

-rw-r--r--  1 edgar  edgar  0 Jan 31 09:15 z

1 edgar  edgar  0 Jan 31 09:15 d

-rw-r--r--  1 edgar  edgar  0 Jan 31 09:15 e

It read from a-v fine and then w-z is weird and then it started over at d. 
I added the extra newlines above for readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is one of the most important things to remember about strings in C? They're meant to be `NUL` terminated!

`read` doesn't add a `NUL` your string - it deals with chunks of raw data, so you have to do that yourself. This also means that you can't pass in the full size of the buffer as you'll need to leave space for the `NUL` to be added

```
       while ((bytes_read = read(pfd[0], readbuf, sizeof(readbuf)-1) > 0)) {
                readbuf[bytes_read]='\0';
                fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", readbuf);
       }
```

Comment: Or tell `printf()` how many bytes to print: `printf("%.*s\n", bytes_read, readbuf);` — using `printf(…)` instead of `fprintf(stdout, …);`.  It also isn't clear that inserting newlines at random points in the output is beneficial; it would probably better to just use `printf("%.*s", bytes_read, readbuf);`.

Comment: I appreciate your response. This is the output.laptop$ ./test             
t
r

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have corrected the problem:

```
do {
        bytes_read = read(pfd[0], readbuf, sizeof(readbuf));
        readbuf[bytes_read] = '\0';
        printf("%s", readbuf);
    } while (bytes_read > 0);
```

Thanks for the assisstance.